# filter values from a coefficient matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, filter, coefficients

I'm new in R.
I have a bit problem picking the data from the matrix.
I generated a coefficient matrix as below:

```
cor_mat <- cor(xxx, method = "spearman")
```

And I would like to take values that the spearman's correlation coefficiency is bigger or smaller than 0.39 or -0.39.

My code is below:

```
x1 <- c()
x2 <- c()
score <- c()
for (i in 1:length(rownames(cor_mat))) {
  for (j in 1:length(colnames(cor_mat))) {
    if(abs(cor_mat[i,j])>0.39 && rownames(cor_mat)[i] != colnames(cor_mat)[j]){
      x1 <- c(x1,paste0(rownames(cor_mat)[i]))
      x2 <- c(x2,colnames(cor_mat)[j])
      score <- c(score, paste0(cor_mat[i,j]))
    }
  }
}
high_cor_df <- data.frame(x1,x2,as.numeric(score))
attach(high_cor_df)
```

It works, but too slow.
Could anyone help me to solve it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach using the `tidyverse` packages.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
xx <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), 
                 y = runif(100), 
                 z = seq(100), 
                 w = seq(100)*runif(100), 
                 p = rev(seq(100))*runif(100))
cor_mat <- cor(xx, method = "spearman")
cor_mat %>% 
   as.data.frame() %>% 
   rownames_to_column(var = "var1") %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -var1, names_to = "var2", values_to = "cor_coeff") %>%
   filter(var1 != var2 & abs(cor_coeff) >= 0.39)

 # A tibble: 4 x 3
  var1  var2  cor_coeff
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 z     w         0.641
2 z     p        -0.599
3 w     z         0.641
4 p     z        -0.599
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it killed due to a memory problem. maybe it is because my matrix is huge. (20,000 x 20,000)